# Calling require does not return the same object

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, winston

I know how module loading is *supposed* to work in node.js, but I'm not observing the correct behavior (and it actually seems there is a slight discrepancy if you look in the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703392/1827734))

Using nodejs 8.2.1, I have the following structure:

```
app
 |
 + server.js
 + log
 |  |
 |  + index.js
 + db
    |
    + index.js
```

In server.js, I call `require('./log')`, and in /log/index.js, I `require('winston')` and configure it like so:

```
let logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      name: 'console',
      level: logLevel,
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      colorize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev',
      timestamp: true
    })
  ]
});
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17737613/1827734), I should be able to just `require('winston')` from any other module, and I would get that same configured instance. What I'm actually seeing is, when I `require('winston')` in `db/index.js`, a default `winston` instance is in memory, with no configuration at all. I've stepped through the `require.cache` as well; no other modules are added to the cache, so as far as I can tell, the same configured instance *should* be returned, if the cache is working properly. I've verified that the code in `log/index.js` is being called before the module in `db/index.js` is being loaded as well.

Any ideas? Should I just be `require`ing my `./log` module in all my dependent modules?

Comment: Shouldn't you require the configured logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas? Should I just be requireing my ./log module in all my dependent modules?

Yes you should. Like you said, when you require a module already required by a parent module, you are accessing to the same object. But actually with winston you are importing a constructor (in fact, to configure it, you define a variable called logger and you create a NEW winson logger).

You should only export logger from logs/index.js (and use const instead of let)

```
 const logger = new (winston.Logger)({ ... })
 module.exports = logger
```

in another module you could do

```
const logger = require('./log/index.js') // './log' is the same
```

logger will always be the same object :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be `require`ing your `./log` file because you are creating a new instance of Winston. Your log file should export the Winston logger instance you created in it with something like:

```
let logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
        name: 'console',
        level: logLevel,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev',
        timestamp: true
    })
    ]
});
module.exports = logger
```

Then in your other code you can:

```
const logger = require('./log')
```

and get the same instance.

Comment: Did something change in module caching in node 8x?

Comment: No modules are still cached. When you create a `new` instance you aren't changing the default instance, you are making a new one. So you need to export that. If you just import Winston, you'll get the default not the one you created and configured.